# Word 2013 - captions will not be update

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office

I have copied a section of text, which contains figures and tables, from another Word 2013 document into a new template document from an older version of Word. For some reason the table and figure numbers will not update with F9. When you right click on a caption 'update field' is blocked out. They are still recognised as fields and will update if you right click on them individually, select 'edit field', and then click ok (without making any change to the field code etc.). However, the associated cross-references do not update. This is the case regardless of whether the new document is in compatibility mode or converted to Word 2013. I would really like some advice so that I don't have to manually update all of these numbers and cross references.

Answer (score 0):

Hi Maybe not a solution but a workaround.
Save the old file into the latest version and copy from that latest version. 
It should work.